# How can I mix command line arguments and filenames for <> in Perl?

Tags: perl, input, arguments

Consider the following silly Perl program:

```
$firstarg = $ARGV[0];

print $firstarg;

$input = <>;

print $input;
```

I run it from a terminal like:

```
perl myprog.pl sample_argument
```

And get this error:

```
Can't open sample_argument: No such file or directory at myprog.pl line 5.
```

Any ideas why this is?  When it gets to the <> is it trying to read from the (non-existent) file, "sample_argument" or something?  And why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<>` is shorthand for "read from the files specified in `@ARGV`, or if `@ARGV` is empty, then read from `STDIN`". In your program, `@ARGV` contains the value `("sample_argument")`, and so Perl tries to read from that file when you use the `<>` operator.

You can fix it by clearing `@ARGV` before you get to the `<>` line:

```
$firstarg = shift @ARGV;
print $firstarg;
$input = <>;       # now @ARGV is empty, so read from STDIN
print $input;
```

Answer (score 8):

See the perlio man page, which reads in part:

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed
> and awk.  Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed
> on the command line.  Here’s how it works: the first time <> is evaluated, the
> @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when
> opened gives you standard input.  The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of
> filenames.

If you want STDIN, use STDIN, not `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, perl consumes the command line arguments as input files for `<>`.  After you've used them, you should consume them yourself with `shift;`

Comment: You have it backwards. Perl doesn't do anything with `@ARGV` by default. It's the behavior of `<>` that's special.

Comment: That's what I was saying.  That <> uses @ARGV unless you consume them yourself with shift.